# PHP json_encoding datas with parent and child categories

Tags: php, json

Iam trying with the json_encoding for about two hours but iam not getting the output as required. Actually this is a requirement for the mobile application developer who is asking in the format which i will explain here.The code below is what i have tried:

```
include_once("class_connection.php");

//Getting the Parent Category

$sqlStr = mysql_query("select catname , id from `category` where `parentid`='0'");
$jsonArray = array();

while ($fetchStr = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlStr)) {

    $jsonArray[] = array("ParentCategory" => $fetchStr["catname"]);
        $id = $fetchStr['id'];

    //Getting child categories from the above parent

    $sqlChildStr = mysql_query("SELECT catname,id,parentid FROM `category` where `parentid`='$id'");

    while ($fetchchildStr = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlChildStr)) {

        $jsonArray[] = array("ChildCategory" => $fetchchildStr["catname"]);
    }

}

echo json_encode(array("JsonOutput" => $jsonArray)) . "<br />";
```

The Output is :

```
"JsonOutput":[{"ParentCategory":"Animals"},{"ChildCategory":"Bear"},{"ChildCategory":"Deer"},{"ChildCategory":"Dolphins"},
{"ParentCategory":"Art"},{"ChildCategory":"Hand Painting"},{"ChildCategory":"Painting"},{"ChildCategory":"3D"},{"ChildCategory":"Abstract"}]}
```

Here , in the above output the parent category array is empty without its child category array. I want to store all the child category array in its parent category array and finally i have to store both parent and child category into the JsonOutput array so i want the output as

```
"JsonOutput":[{
"ParentCategory":"Animals" : [{
    {"ChildCategory":"Bear"},{"ChildCategory":"Deer"},{"ChildCategory":"Dolphins"}
]}
"ParentCategory":"Arts" : [{
    {"ChildCategory":"Hand Painting"},{"ChildCategory":"Painting"},{"ChildCategory":"3D"}, {"ChildCategory":"Abstract"}
]}
]}
```

Comment: Your desired output does not look like valid JSON to me.

Comment: You seem to be looking to format (or prettify) your JSON output. But why is that necessary in the first place? Are human beings going to process it?

Comment: @Pekka: Look more closely, it's not necessarily about prettification: `"ParentCategory":"Animals" : [{` <- just about creating invalid JSON.

Comment: @hakre right. OP, you really need to clarify what you're doing here

Comment: @user 1850534: Please edit your question. In it's current form it is not clear what you are asking for. The output you want is not valid JSON. Please fix that, you will not see much support here for invalid JSON. Also please make more clear what is particularly the problematic part for you to create the wanted output. Is it to create the hierarchical structure for example?

Comment: Firstly your PHP script adds array values to both parent and child categories in the same level of your `jsonArray` array. You should be looping `while ($fetchchildStr = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlChildStr)) {` and add as a subarray of the parent array. Secondly you can't have three values (its key=>value pairs) in json, so you need to rethink this. You shouldn't need the label "ParentCategory"

Comment: The question is fairly clear: he is getting a flat array of objects, he needs a two dimensional array: an array of parents, each parent containing 0 or more children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to do this (only the important bits are shown):

```
$jsonArray = array();
while ($parentCat = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlStr)) {
    $temp = array(
        "ParentCategory" => $parentCat["catname"]
    );
    while ($childCat = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlChildStr)) {
        $temp["ChildCategory"][] = array(
            "ChildCategory" => $childCat["catname"]
        );
    }
    $jsonArray[] = $temp;
}
```

I used a temporary variable for storing and manipulating the parent category. This gets added to the main array at the end of loop.

Answer (score -1):

Please use the following codes, give the index inside the while loop...

```
$jsonArray = {};
while ($fetchStr = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlStr)) {

    //$jsonArray[] = array("ParentCategory" => $fetchStr["catname"]);
        $id = $fetchStr['id'];

    //Getting child categories from the above parent

    $sqlChildStr = mysql_query("SELECT catname,id,parentid FROM `category` where `parentid`='$id'");

    while ($fetchchildStr = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlChildStr)) {

        $jsonArray["ParentCategory"][$fetchStr["catname"]] = array("ChildCategory" => $fetchchildStr["catname"]);
    }

}

echo json_encode(array("JsonOutput" => $jsonArray)) . "<br />";
```